How to read more specific configurations in two dimensions which only have been overwritten partially
I am trying to read configuration entries from a database which has a base "project" and a base "machine" defined by the ID 0. The base configuration (key + value) can be overwritten by more specific projects and machines. I'm using HeidiSQL on MariaDB.



project_id
machine_id
Key
Value
Interpretation




0
0
Uc_max
5000
Machine 2 and Project 2


1
0
Uc_max
4000
Machine 2 and Project 1


0
1
Uc_max
10000
Machine 1 and Project 2


1
1
Uc_max
15000
Machine 1 and Project 1


0
2
Uc_max
20000
Machine 2 and Project 1




edit1:
The interpretation column shows only one possible way of interpretation. The idea of the table is to define only those more specifc values, which are needed. All combinations, which are not specified, should default to the base project / machine. So e.g. the entry for project_id 0 and machine_id 0 will also be valid for project_id 7 and machine_id 9. The last entry (project_id 0 and machine_id 2) is valid for machine 2 and all projects.

I have started with the following minimal example table:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `overwrite`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `overwrite` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `machine_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key` char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

DELETE FROM `overwrite`;
INSERT INTO `overwrite` (`id`, `project_id`, `machine_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES
    (0, 0, 0, 'Uc_max', 5000),
    (1, 1, 0, 'Uc_max', 4000),
    (2, 0, 1, 'Uc_max', 10000),
    (3, 1, 1, 'Uc_max', 15000),
    (4, 0, 2, 'Uc_max', 20000);

With my current query I can read the first four entries correctly. Unfortunately, when I try to read the configuration for project 1 and machine 2 no entry is being shown. As no entry for project 1 exists, it should default to 0 and return the entry with ID 4.
SELECT o.`id`, o.`project_id`, o.`machine_id`, o.`key`, o.`value`
FROM overwrite o
LEFT JOIN (
     -- get all keys, for specific project_id
    SELECT DISTINCT o1.`key`
    FROM overwrite o1
    -- insert specific project_id here
     WHERE o1.`project_id` = 1
) subquery_project ON o.`key` = subquery_project.`key`
LEFT JOIN (
    -- Get all keys for specific machine_id
    SELECT DISTINCT o1.`key`
    FROM overwrite o1
    -- insert specific machine_id here
    WHERE o1.`machine_id` = 2
) subquery_machine ON o.`key` = subquery_machine.`key`
-- always read entries for 0, replace second ID with specifc project / machine
WHERE o.`project_id` IN (0, 1)
AND o.`machine_id` IN (0, 2)
AND (
    -- If project_id is 0, include only if there is no more specific projects entry
    (o.`project_id` = 0 AND subquery_project.`key` IS NULL)
    -- Always include more specific project entries
    OR o.`project_id` = 1
)
AND (
    -- If machine_id is 0, include only if there is no more specific machine entry
    (o.`machine_id` = 0 AND subquery_machine.`key` IS NULL)
    -- Always include more specific machine entries
    OR o.`machine_id` = 2
)

I understand, that subquery_project.key will NOT be null in this case and causes the issue. Still I cannot figure out how to modify the query or create a different one, which works fine.

edit2:
I want to save and retrieve configurations for a specific project but also want to consider global configurations (project_id = 0) only when there's no override for the specific project. That way, only overrides and the global configuration get saved to the database. Keys for which no specific override exists, will have the values of the global configuration (project_id = 0).
This got more complex as not only a global configuration exists per project, but also per machine.
Please give me feedback, if more information is needed on the concept of overriding and how those overrides are stored in the database.
My problem is, that I cannot retrieve the correct configuration values in all cases. The SELECT from above should return line with ID 4, but doesn't return anything. If I adjust it to find the valid configurations for project 7 and machine 1 it returns correctly the line with ID 2:
SELECT o.`id`, o.`project_id`, o.`machine_id`, o.`key`, o.`value`
FROM overwrite o
LEFT JOIN (
     -- get all keys, for specific project_id
    SELECT DISTINCT o1.`key`
    FROM overwrite o1
    -- insert specific project_id here
     WHERE o1.`project_id` = 7
) subquery_project ON o.`key` = subquery_project.`key`
LEFT JOIN (
    -- Get all keys for specific machine_id
    SELECT DISTINCT o1.`key`
    FROM overwrite o1
    -- insert specific machine_id here
    WHERE o1.`machine_id` = 1
) subquery_machine ON o.`key` = subquery_machine.`key`
-- always read entries for 0, replace second ID with specifc project / machine
WHERE o.`project_id` IN (0, 7)
AND o.`machine_id` IN (0, 1)
AND (
    -- If project_id is 0, include only if there is no more specific projects entry
    (o.`project_id` = 0 AND subquery_project.`key` IS NULL)
    -- Always include more specific project entries
    OR o.`project_id` = 7
)
AND (
    -- If machine_id is 0, include only if there is no more specific machine entry
    (o.`machine_id` = 0 AND subquery_machine.`key` IS NULL)
    -- Always include more specific machine entries
    OR o.`machine_id` = 1
)


edit3:
updated the values in the SQL table to the same as the table to avoid confusion.

edit 4:
As @ValNik has figured out, I wasn't aware that the result may be ambiguously. Therefore, the decision was made, that the project is always more important than the machine.

Which dbms are you using? (HeidiSQL can connect to a bunch of different dbms servers.)

Provide a complete, and consistent [mcve].

I've added that I am using MariaDB. @jarlh What are you missing in my minimal example?

Does the specified result match the given sample data?

I tried my best by providing sample data and describing the desired result.

Provided sample data and shown desired output must match completely.

Could you please be so kind and show me, where they don't match? I don't understand the issue. The table in my post is for demonstrating the concept. After that, I have provided SQL to create a table with sample data. After that, I have provided a SQL which can be executed against that sample data. It runs and returns no error, but also no result. I have described which row I would like to be fetched.

I've spent a few minutes trying to understand what this is about and have failed. Maybe you need to work on your problem statement.

Value  in table(5000,4000,10000 ...) not match values in DDL (0,1,2 ...). There is no reason to create such ambiguities in the question. Correct the data in DDL.

If we consider pair (project_id=1,machine_id=2) for project_id default value for key Uc_max is 4000, machine_id default is 20000. What value will you choose and why?

Thank you @ValNik for the more specific input. I have updated the table to avoid confusion. You found an issue in my database concept. Thank you very much. I need to solve that one, before thinking about how to retrieve the lines.

After the excellent input of @ValNik and the decision to prioritize the project over the machine, it seems to be much easier than I thought, and the following query seems to read all configuration keys properly.
SELECT o.id, o.project_id, o.machine_id, o.key, o.value
FROM overwrite o
WHERE o.id = COALESCE(
    (SELECT o1.id FROM overwrite o1 WHERE o1.key = o.key AND o1.project_id = 1 AND o1.machine_id = 2 LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT o2.id FROM overwrite o2 WHERE o2.key = o.key AND o2.project_id = 1 AND o2.machine_id = 0 LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT o3.id FROM overwrite o3 WHERE o3.key = o.key AND o3.project_id = 0 AND o3.machine_id = 2 LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT o4.id FROM overwrite o4 WHERE o4.key = o.key AND o4.project_id = 0 AND o4.machine_id = 0 LIMIT 1)
);

Sorry for the confusion and thank you very much for the help!

The most appropriate way, in my opinion, is to apply a series of JOIN's to select the specifc values for tuple(key,project,machine) as well as the default values.
There main table - list of tuple(key,project_id,machine_id).
First join table overwrite - on completely fit key,project_id,machine_id.
Second join - on key,project  with machine_id=0 - that's project defaults.
Third join - on key,machine  with project_id=0 - that's machine defaults.
Last JOIN - on key with project_id=0 and machine_id=0 - key defaults.
Result value is first not null value from (project_machine,project default,machine default,key default).
See example
With source data



id
project_id
machine_id
key
value




0
0
0
Uc_max
5000


1
1
0
Uc_max
4000


2
0
1
Uc_max
10000


3
1
1
Uc_max
15000


4
0
2
Uc_max
20000



This query retrieves all values for all keys for all combinations (key,project_id,machine_id) in table overwrite.
with mp as(
   select p.project_id,m.machine_id,k
   from (select distinct project_id from overwrite where project_id<>0
      ) p
   cross join (select distinct machine_id from overwrite where machine_id<>0
      ) m 
   cross join (select distinct `key` as k from overwrite 
      ) k
)
select mp.project_id,mp.machine_id,mp.k
  ,coalesce(pm.value,pd.value,md.value,def.value) key_value  -- result key
  ,pm.value project_machine_value -- project and machine
  ,pd.project_id pd_project_id,pd.value project_default -- project defaults
  ,md.machine_id md_machine_id,md.value machine_default -- machine defaults
  ,def.value key_default_value -- default value for key
from mp
left join overwrite pm on pm.key=mp.k and pm.project_id=mp.project_id 
  and pm.machine_id=mp.machine_id
left join overwrite pd on pd.key=mp.k and pd.project_id=mp.project_id 
  and pd.machine_id=0
left join overwrite md on md.key=mp.k and md.machine_id=mp.machine_id 
  and md.project_id=0
left join overwrite def on def.key=mp.k 
  and def.machine_id=0 and def.project_id=0
order by mp.project_id,mp.machine_id




project_id
machine_id
k
key_value
project_machine_value
pd_project_id
project_default
md_machine_id
machine_default
key_default_value




1
1
Uc_max
15000
15000
1
4000
1
10000
5000


1
2
Uc_max
4000
null
1
4000
2
20000
5000



This query retrieve value for assigned (key,project_id,machine_id).
with mp as(
   select 1 as project_id,7 as machine_id,'Uc_max' as k
)
select mp.project_id,mp.machine_id,mp.k
  ,coalesce(pm.value,pd.value,md.value,def.value) key_value  -- result key
  ,pm.value project_machine_value -- project and machine
  ,pd.project_id pd_project_id,pd.value project_default -- project defaults
  ,md.machine_id md_machine_id,md.value machine_default -- machine defaults
  ,def.value key_default_value -- default value for key
from mp
left join overwrite pm on pm.key=mp.k and pm.project_id=mp.project_id 
  and pm.machine_id=mp.machine_id
left join overwrite pd on pd.key=mp.k and pd.project_id=mp.project_id 
  and pd.machine_id=0
left join overwrite md on md.key=mp.k and md.machine_id=mp.machine_id 
  and md.project_id=0
left join overwrite def on def.key=mp.k 
  and def.machine_id=0 and def.project_id=0
;




project_id
machine_id
k
key_value
project_machine_value
pd_project_id
project_default
md_machine_id
machine_default
key_default_value




1
7
Uc_max
4000
null
1
4000
null
null
5000



If the query returns more than 1 row, then there is an ambiguity in the table - you must decide what to do in this case.
fiddle
Example for different combinations of project_id,machine_id values
with mp as(
   select 1 as project_id,7 as machine_id,'Uc_max' as k
  union all
  select 2 as project_id,1 as machine_id,'Uc_max' as k
  union all
  select 2 as project_id,3 as machine_id,'Uc_max' as k
)

select mp.project_id,mp.machine_id,mp.k
  ,coalesce(pm.value,pd.value,md.value,def.value) key_value  -- result key
  ,pm.value project_machine_value -- project and machine
  ,pd.project_id pd_project_id,pd.value project_default -- project defaults
  ,md.machine_id md_machine_id,md.value machine_default -- machine defaults
  ,def.value key_default_value -- default value for key
from mp
left join overwrite pm on pm.key=mp.k and pm.project_id=mp.project_id 
  and pm.machine_id=mp.machine_id
left join overwrite pd on pd.key=mp.k and pd.project_id=mp.project_id 
  and pd.machine_id=0
left join overwrite md on md.key=mp.k and md.machine_id=mp.machine_id 
  and md.project_id=0
left join overwrite def on def.key=mp.k 
  and def.machine_id=0 and def.project_id=0




project_id
machine_id
k
key_value
project_machine_value
pd_project_id
project_default
md_machine_id
machine_default
key_default_value




2
1
Uc_max
10000
null
null
null
1
10000
5000


1
7
Uc_max
4000
null
1
4000
null
null
5000


2
3
Uc_max
5000
null
null
null
null
null
5000



fiddle
Queries with join are useful for data management.
To retrive data use this short query(possible with coalesce(...) for single value):
select *
  ,(select max(value) value from overwrite t1 
    where t1.`key`=t.`key` and t1.project_id=t.project_id and t1.machine_id=t.machine_id)pm
  ,(select max(value) value from overwrite t2 
    where t2.`key`=t.`key` and t2.project_id=t.project_id and  t2.machine_id=0)pv
  ,(select max(value) value from overwrite t3
    where t3.`key`=t.`key` and t3.project_id=0 and t3.machine_id=t.machine_id )mv
  ,(select max(value) value from overwrite t4
    where t4.`key`=t.`key` and t4.project_id=0 and t4.machine_id=0)dv
from ( select 'Uc_max' as `key`, 1 project_id,2 machine_id) t





key
project_id
machine_id
pm
pv
mv
dv




Uc_max
1
2
null
4000
20000
5000



fiddle
